# What is the meaning of this sentence, "there's nowhere else on earth I'd rather be."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> "There's nowhere else on earth I'd rather be"

Comment: PSJ - it means *I would prefer to be here rather than any other place on earth*.

Comment: People who say "There's nowhere else on earth I'd rather be," are content being where they are.  They do not wish to be in any other place than where they are currently.  People who say this might also say, "This place is my favorite place on earth."  For some people that place might be with their families in their hometowns.  For others it might be in a favorite vacation/holiday location.  Each person's favorite place is unique and uniquely personal.

Comment: [I have often walked down this street before](http://youtu.be/YtbFwWkB4b8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has its simple literal meaning. The speaker is where they wish to be and would not prefer to be anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It just means he or she is simply enjoying the NOW. The present moment. That's all. There is only one meaning to the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary,

> Would rather...(than) (usually reduced to **'d rather**) would prefer to

In your sentence, the author means they don't wish to be in any place on earth other than their current location.